# Is there any tool to check Performace of the mobile web site on real mobile devices?

Tags: performance, load-testing, mobile

Could you please suggest a tool that can be used to measure performance of a web site on real Mobile devices like Android, iOS etc. ?

Is there any tool that can be used on Mobile devices and on a desktop machine too?

We are small scale company primarily looking for Open Source or Paid tools with Trial versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jmeter to test performance of your site in mobile and desktop also.

Please check perfect guide : [Performance testing](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/186249-load-test-mobile-apps-easily)